# How to find the most frequent element of a list that is not in another list?

Tags: python, list

Find the most frequent element of list `A` that is not in list `B`:

```
A = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 12, 23, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 20, 21, 22, 22]
B = [2, 4, 5, 22]
```

I'm looking for the most concise solution.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider just counting them with [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and filtering based on list `B`. It could be faster than using `.count()` in a loop because it only needs to loop through the lists once. Whereas `.count()` needs to loop through multiple times (for every number) to count it.

```
from collections import Counter

A = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 12, 23, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 20, 21, 22, 22, 6]
B = [2, 4, 5, 22]

s = set(B)
Counter(n for n in A if n not in s).most_common(1)
# [(3, 4)] # the number and count
```

Comment: (average) Linear time since set membership checking is constant time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want concise, here's short one using `Counter` from `collections`:

```
max({*A}-{*B},key=Counter(A).get)
```